# Why is inotify losing events?

Tags: perl, logging, event-handling, inotify

I need to process large (~100s) of syslog messages using Perl and [Linux::Inotify2](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Linux%3a%3aInotify2).

I wrote a test script which generates log messages continuously. To process events, my Perl script looks like this-

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Linux::Inotify2 ;
use Time::HiRes qw(usleep nanosleep);
# create a new object
 my $inotify = new Linux::Inotify2
    or die "Unable to create new inotify object: $!" ;

 # create watch
 $inotify->watch ("/var/log/messages",  IN_ACCESS|IN_OPEN|IN_CLOSE|IN_MODIFY|IN_Q_OVERFLOW)
    or die "watch creation failed" ;
my $count=0;
 while () {
   my @events = $inotify->read;
   unless (@events > 0) {
     print "read error: $!";
     last ;
   }
   #printf "mask\t%d\n", $_->mask foreach @events ; 
   $count++;
   print $count."\n";
   usleep(100000);
 }
```

If I un-comment usleep function to simulate processing, I notice that when I stop the log generator script, the inotify script doesn't catch up with it. In other words, the inotify Perl script is losing events.

Neither do I see any Overflow message.

How do I make sure that even if my processing is slow, I don't lose messages. In other words, how do I define a "buffer" where messages can be stored temporarily?

Comment: Which module are you using?  There's more than one Perl interface to inotify.

Comment: Also, you seem to be missing some code.  For instance, you never populate `@events` with anything.  And your `usleep` call is outside any loop.

Comment: How do you determine that events are missing? To count number of events you could try: `$count += @events`.

Comment: I don't see any attempt to check if the queue overflowed.  Also, what is `/proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_queued_events` set to?

Comment: put a sleep(1) before doing last to avoid looping if there is no events. Maybe you flooded with queries the inotify.

Comment: You could consider configuring rsyslog to send syslog messages to your perl process rather than using the filesystem / inotify as an intermediary.

Comment: Going along with the rsyslog suggestion from @LucaFilipozzi , you can also use Syslog-NG the same way.  If you need to do real-time log processing, sending the logs directly to your script (with Syslog-NG or rsyslog) is usually the best way to do it.  That removes your need to handle the file, you can just process stdin and be done.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to try to address your root problem, even though it doesn't exactly answer your question.

I think using inotify is too low-level a way of resolving this.  If I were you, I'd be looking at a higher-level solution that frees you from the details of finding new events, and lets you concentrate on processing the log events.  No need to reinvent the wheel when there's a bunch of good ones already available.

My first choice would be to use a  modern syslog daemon (personally I prefer Syslog-NG, but rsyslog would work well enough, too), and tie that directly to your script.  Instead of your script going through all the work of tracking when new events come in, your script just processes `stdin`, and the syslog daemon automatically sends new logs to your script as they come in.  I've used this method successfully on numerous occasions.

My second choice would be to let a higher-level Perl module do as much of the heavy lifting as possible.  The first place I'd look for that would be `File::Tail`.  Like before, this frees you from the problems of watching the file itself, and lets you concentrate on the processing.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [Inotify on CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/Linux-Inotify2-1.22/Inotify2.pm#Callback_Interface) and have you tried it with the callback to check all the errors:

```
 $inotify->watch ("/etc/passwd", IN_ACCESS | IN_MODIFY, sub {
      my $e = shift;
      print "$e->{w}{name} was accessed\n" if $e->IN_ACCESS;
      print "$e->{w}{name} was modified\n" if $e->IN_MODIFY;
      print "$e->{w}{name} is no longer mounted\n" if $e->IN_UNMOUNT;
      print "events for $e->{w}{name} have been lost\n" if $e->IN_Q_OVERFLOW;
  });
```

Also, you are watching for almost every event on the file. I'd only watch for modification events or a smaller subset of events to see if the problem still existed.